# What I have doing wrong with pushing existing code to VSTS

Tags: git

I have prepared PowerShell script for push Visual Studio solutions to VSTS.

Unfortunately, this happens several weeks ago and now I cant remember what command I have used. Only I have output window from Powershell ISE:

(lines starting with +++ are command which I probably used by tonight analyse)

```
+++git init
Reinitialized existing Git repository in D:/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/C++_Projects/Mira_kompilator/.git/
Removing .gitignore
Removing Code/
Removing Dokumentace/
Removing Helpful stuff/
+++
git : fatal: pathspec '*' did not match any files 
At line:6 char:1
+ git add *
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (fatal: pathspec...match any files:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

On branch master

+++git commit

Initial commit

nothing to commit

+++git push
git : error: src refspec refs/heads/master does not match any.
At line:8 char:1
+ git push -f
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (error: src refs... not match any.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

error: failed to push some refs to 'https://.visualstudio.com/_git/Mira_kompilator'
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script removed all the files, before adding nothing (since the files were gone), failing to commit as a result.

Make sure to try it in a new cloned repo manually first (meaning without Powershell script) to be sure this is working.
Use git add . instead of git add *.
And make sure your remote repo URL is correct (`https://.visualstudio.com` seems strange)

Clone your remote repo then:

```
cd /path/to/local/clone
# modify some files
git add .
git commit -m "first commit"
git push
```